# Copying from one PF in a lib to another PF in a lib and making it a CSV?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I don't think the OS will copy from one PF to another PF using comma delimiters so does anyone have a utility out there that will do that?

I don't want to use the IFS just PF's in libraries.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense...what do you think you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Although I agree with @Charles , generating a general .CSV format in a PF in one library by copying from a PF in another library works just fine. What problem are you having?

Comment: Why the down votes on an answerable question is beyond what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @danny117 I didn't downvote; but my problem w/the question is that CPYTOIMPF seems already understood by the OP, hence the closing sentence. So why think the OS doesn't allow it into another PF? I.e., what is "the problem"? I **think** the problem is that "program-described" PFs are not known by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
CPYTOIMPF FROMFILE(QTEMP/Z1) 
          TOFILE(QTEMP/Z2)   
          FLDDLM(',')        

/*z2 is flat file*/
```

Comment: This as an easy way to get entire row of db into delimited string.  The delimited string can then be easily passed to other services.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: lOl Anyone who's ever worked on the iseries would realize this answer far  surpasses IBM documentation.

Comment: Also two people down voted the question before I answered it.

Comment: "... far surpasses IBM documentation." - best comment I've seen in a long time. Unfortunately very accurate too.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little odd, maybe your terminology is off. If you at trying to copy a physical file to a stream file in CSV format, danny117's answer will do what you want. If you are trying to copy from one PF to another PF, use `CPYF`, no intermediate CSV required. If you really want the intermediate CSV, start with `CPYTOIMPF` as specified in danny's answer, but then use `CPYFRMIMPF` to get the CSV into the next PF. I guess that could be useful if your fields match, but have different names.

BTW: `CPYTOIMPF` and `CPYFRMIMPF` do not have to use the IFS.